# Contact form in content type

Tags: nodes, entities

I've made a content type User. Each user has a field email. I will not display the email but I would like a way for visitors to contact each user. So I am looking for a way to have a simple contact form inside a content type.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the module [Email Field](https://drupal.org/project/email) to create your email field you can set the field to be displayed as a contact form. You will find the setting to turn the field into a contact form under Display settings for the field.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the following modules in addition to [Email Field](https://drupal.org/project/email), which performs similar function as you need

[Email Contact](https://drupal.org/project/email_contact)

> This module provides display formatters for the email field to display
> email as a link to the contact form, or as an inline contact form.
> Depends on the Email module.

[Views Contact Form](https://drupal.org/project/views_contact_form)

> **Use cases**
>
> You need to create a block, an attachement or a page with a
> custom URL with a contact form inside that will send an email to a
> particular person (the recipient is taken from any field you want),
> you will use this module, Views and/or Panels. You need to create
> block that will send an email to the author of a content. You need to
> create block that will send an email to an email field, referenced
> through a reference in another content. Instead of displaying an email
> field as an email link (with mailto:), display a contact form instead
> and the recipient is taken from the field.

Answer (score 0):

[Contact Form On Node](https://drupal.org/project/contact_form_on_node) module add a contact form right under the node. You can choose:

```
to add a contact form on teaser,
to add a contact form on full view,
to add a contact link on teaser,
to add a contact link on full view,
which content types these settings will apply to.
```

or

[Author Contact](https://drupal.org/project/authorcontact) Creates a block that shows a contact form that when submitted, sends a simple contact email to the author of the current node. This might be useful for a multi-user blog or auction site.

or

[Node feedback](https://drupal.org/project/node_feedback) offers a check box on the node form asking the author to allow the visitors of the node to send feedback/request for the node using the personal/site wide contact form. Author can choose which category will be selected when user request the node information or wish to give her/his feedback. Admin can select between the individual contact form and site wide contact form. This is ideal for social networking sites as well as sites maintained by a single user.